# Can we format to f2fs?

Tags: format, f2fs

i tried to format to f2fs but it's impossible. It's gray and can't be chosen.

I think we only can format /home and /tmp , we can't format /. Right ?

[I tried this guide i found here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241328) , but nothing. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: You can't format a mounted partition.

Comment: can we not stick to details ? ok let's say i'm booting from a live usb to do it.